# Send email with new entries when they are added to a log file

Tags: logging, monitoring

I have a log file (`/var/log/forever.err`) which must stay empty. Entries there basically mean trouble.
I would like to do the following:

- Monitor the file
- If the size changes, email me the new contents

I could probably code this, although I DO tend to reinvent the wheel. If I were to code it, I would probably:

- Get the file's size
- Put a system watch on the file
- If the size changes, sleep for 10 seconds (giving it time to finish), and then read the new bytes (I know what they are since I had the size)
- Send an email with the contents
- Put a watch on the file again

Is there something that *already* does this?

Comment: Logrotate can email you the content of a file. Logrotate does have a granularity of a day but you can force a logrotate. As an added bonus you keep revisions of your logfile.

Comment: Trouble is, I don't really want to "rotate" the logs, and anyway not at "set intervals"...

Comment: Are these logs from `syslogd` or something custom/proprietary?

Comment: Proprietary. They are redirects of outputs.